# How connected to a pc from an external network with ssh

Tags: ssh, internet

I need to access to a computer via `ssh` from an external network.

The pc must be accessible using the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` ssh key, i' m not sure how connect.

I set some NAT (i don' t know if is necessary) those are the fields of my router:

```
Ip address: <local_ip> (of the pc with which I will try to connect)
Protocol: TCP/IP
External port: 22 - 22
Internal port: 22 - 22
```

I tried:

```
ssh user@<public_ip>:22  (immediately)  ---> Name or service not known
ssh user@<public_ip>   (some time) ----> Connection timed out
```

What is the `ssh` command to use? Do I need to NAT? Do I need something else?

Is it possible to access a pc with a public connection (via `ssh`) from my home network?

Comment: Is this a question about how to set up an SSH server on the machine locally or about how to configure your router?

Comment: @Kusalananda  What is the ssh command to use? Do I need to NAT? Do I need something else?

Comment: Does your ISP filter port 22? If so, you may need to pick an external port other than 22. (BTW: you specify the port for the openssh client like: `ssh -p 1234 user@host`)

Comment: @derobert finally someone that tell me of use ssh, thanks. host=public_ip ?

Comment: @Scorpion yes, you can use your public IP there (or a host name corresponding to it if, e.g., you sign up with a dynamic DNS provider — or even simpler if you have a static IP address)

Comment: @derobert I have a static IP so I don' t need DNS or host name.

Comment: @Scorpion you don't *need* one, but using one will make your life easier in the future — a, it's a lot easier to remember and recognize a name vs. an IP address; b, it's a lot easier to change a single DNS entry if you ever have to change IP addresses. (BTW: since you have a static IP, you probably don't have ISP filtering — or at least your ISP can be asked to turn it off).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the following:

1. As 'derobert' suggested, firstly make sure your ISP does not block incoming connections to port 22.
2. You would need to forward the port (22) to destination machine (the machine you want to reach via SSH from external network. Usually this is called `port forwarding` or `port mapping` and a simple google search should reveal how to do that. After that, you can try to connect to your machine as:

> ssh -vv -p PORT user@public_ip

`-vv` will enable the verbose output so that you can see what is going in behind the scenes.

Currently, when you try to SSH to your public IP, it is the router responding to port 22 (and most home routers don't have SSH server to cater SSH requests to themselves).

Comment: My router call port forwarding port mapping. There is also a section `simplified port mapping` in service i can select ssh.  I added the ip but nothing. So my router can' t handle ssh?

Comment: If you've set the port mapping correctly, then it most probably is the ISP blocking incoming connections to port 22. You can test this by changing the port number for SSH in the config file and then changing the port mapping to this new port number. Then try to connect to your machine from external n/w using new port number as: `ssh -vv -p PORT user@public_ip`. `-vv` will enable the verbose output so that you can see what is going in behind the scenes.

Comment: If i check here https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ it seems that all ports are closed. Anyway meanwhile the public IP has changed and using `ssh -vv -p 22 user@<public_ip>` i can finally connect. I asked the provider to open the ports and maybe they give me a new IP with open ports. I don't known if the option in simplified port mapping is needed.

Comment: If you add the `ssh` command in your answer i will accept it.